# What is Windows 8 core?

Tags: windows-8

I've found some references, [when looking for information on WAIK installs of Windows 8](http://www.eightforums.com/installation-setup/6824-professional-core-editions-windows-8-both-rp-setup-iso.html) of a varient called Windows 8 core, that can be installed off the professional edition disk. There's also a mention of it [on Win Super Site that says](http://www.winsupersite.com/article/windows8/windows-8-144015)

> The cheapest, called MSDN Operating Systems, costs $699 a year ($499
>   renewal), and of course includes Windows 8 (Core), Windows 8 Pro, and
>   Windows 8 Enterprise. You get five licenses each for Windows 8 Core
>   and Pro, and one Multiple Activation Key (MAK) for Windows 8
>   Enterprise.

What is Windows 8 core?  Is it the new 'home' edition or something else?  What differentiates it from the pro and enterprise editions?

Comment: It's not part of the proper name; the word "core" is taking its generic English language meaning as a modifier, to differentiate this edition of Windows 8 from the editions whose names have suffices.

Comment: It looks like in Windows 8 Core means what Home means in Windows 7 and Windows 10.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Windows 8 (Core) is simply Windows 8. It's the base (core) product, which Pro and Enterprise built on.

And I say that because I can find no official reference to a *Core product* and it was in parenthesis in your source (compared to the other editions where no parenthesis was used).

Comment: The only references to it are in the logs. If you look at various Setup logs, you'll find lines like: Source OS: Host SKU Info: Edition = 'Core', Edition Type = 'Complete', Product Name = 'Windows 8', Arch = amd64, etc.

Answer (score 44):

**The "Core" from "Windows 8 Core" simply emphasizes it is the "plain" Windows 8 and not one of the other versions (Pro, Enterprise, RT).**

Paul Thurrott of WinSuperSite explicitly names Windows 8 Core in his giant [comparison table of different Windows 8 editions](http://www.winsupersite.com/article/windows8/windows-8-secrets-book-guide-product-editions-144067) (notice the plain "Windows 8" is absent from the table because it is referred to as "Core"):

[image]

[More information about the different editions of Windows 8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8_editions).

Comment: Well that's confusing.

Comment: I'm pretty dubious about this table. For one, RT apparently only supports dual core CPUs, yet [the specifications for the Surface RT](http://www.microsoft.com/Surface/en-US/surface-with-windows-rt/specifications) say it has a quad core Tegra 3. I'm also almost certain that RT can play MP4 (H.264) video.

Comment: @JamWaffles: cores ≥ physical processors. Theoretically, Windows RT  could support two Tegra 3's for a total of 8 cores. Paul Thurrott is a very reputable source for Windows-related information.

Comment: Interestingly MS has their own graph sans enterprise edition that 'just' calls it Windows 8 in a blog post that was linked from winsupersite. Both answers were good, but I found oliver's answer clearer. Upvotes all around though!

Answer (score 1):

It means the "Home" edition for all intents and purposes. Perhaps the best source for this is MSFT's own site (for Windows programmers). Search for "PRODUCT_CORE" here (which programmers rely on) and look at the "Meaning" column:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724358(v=vs.85).aspx

Note that it currently refers to it as "Windows 10 Home" but all other editions have their own qualifiers (e.g., search for "PRODUCT_PROFESSIONAL", "PRODUCT_ENTERPRISE", etc.) In fact, prior to the release of Windows 10, the "Meaning" column for "PRODUCT_CORE" (at the same link) referred to it as simply "Windows 8", which normally means the home edition by default (in the absence of the terms "Pro", "Professional" or "Enterprise").