# What is the difference between Norton Internet Security (2014 and earlier) and the new Norton Security?

Tags: norton-internet-security, norton-security

Symantec recently released a new product called *Norton Security*, which seems to be the successor to *Norton Internet Security*, but I need help understanding the differences between these products and the new features introduced with Norton Security.

What are the key differences between Norton Internet Security and the newer Norton Security?

Comment: Related: http://betanews.com/2014/09/24/norton-security-2015-now-available/

Comment: Just curious - this seems localised to 2014 and 2015 - what happens in 2016? A community FAQ is something that needs to be relevant far in the future, and I'm not sure this counts as such.

Comment: Ok.. I've cleaned up the comments somewhat. Feel free to take any disagreements to meta, or better yet vote appropriately. I do think suitability of the question as a community FAQ is still questionable, so leaving comments related to that for now. I'd note that this [question](http://superuser.com/questions/490663/what-is-windows-8-core) can be seen as *somewhat* of a precedent and any answers *should* be backed up with sources - Something official off norton would be just perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Norton Security gives you 5 licenses and it's the latest and recommended version.
NIS is the 2013-14 version and gives you 3 licenses (5 on some areas)
You have the right for a refund 60 days after your purchase.

Comment: Your answer isn't really complete. Among other things, it doesn't mention the fact that Norton Security can be used to protect mobile devices.

Comment: Correct. The user can install in Windows, Mac, Android and iOS

Comment: If you have relevant information to add, you can always edit it into your answer.

Comment: Good to know, thanx DL!